# Asp.net Core 2.2, custom middleware for authorizing files outside of wwwroot, but httpcontext.User is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need to allow access to a directory of static files only if the user is authenticated.

I have set up a middleware to check each request as it comes. I can get the request no problem, but the Httpcontext User is always null. I am using cookies authentication and not Identity. I have added the default authentication cookies scheme to the sign in as well as the services in startup.cs. I'm not sure why I can't get the user. This is based off of Scott Allen's tutorial https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2015/10/06/authorization-policies-and-middleware-in-asp-net-5.aspx

**Startup.cs**

```
   public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
                .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

            services.AddAuthentication( options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignOutScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {

                    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/Index";
                    options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
            });
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("Authenticated", policy => policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser());
            });

            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {


            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();



            app.UseProtectFolder(new ProtectFolderOptions
            {
                Path = "/StaticFiles",
                PolicyName = "Authenticated",

            });

            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Static_Files")),
                RequestPath = "/StaticFiles"
            });




            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseAuthentication();


            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            });
        }

        private object RedirectResult()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

**MiddleWare**

```
    public class ProtectFolderOptions
    {
        public PathString Path { get; set; }
        public string PolicyName { get; set; }
    }
    // Extension method used to add the middleware to the HTTP request pipeline.
    public static class ProtectFolderExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseProtectFolder(this IApplicationBuilder builder, ProtectFolderOptions options)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<ProtectFolder>(options);
        }
    }

    // You may need to install the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions package into your project
    public class ProtectFolder
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly PathString _path;
        private readonly string _policyName;

        public ProtectFolder(RequestDelegate next,ProtectFolderOptions options)
        {
            _next = next;
            _path = options.Path;
            _policyName = options.PolicyName;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, IAuthorizationService authorizationService)
        {


            if (httpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(_path))
            {
                var authorized = await authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(
                                    httpContext.User, null, _policyName);
                if (authorized.Succeeded == false)
                {
                    await httpContext.ChallengeAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                    return;
                }
            }

            await _next(httpContext);
        }
    }
```

The middleware is able to check the request. But httpcontext doesn't contain user even after I signed in, and I always get redirected to the login page.

Comment: Add your middleware after auth middleware, the order matters.

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding, do you mean app.UseAuthentication() should precede my app.UseProtectFolder(...) ? @VidmantasBlazevicius

Comment: Yes, that’s the middleware that creates ClaimsPrincipal